# Trying to remove the price and subscription from products in WooCommerce

Tags: css, woocommerce

I am trying to remove the price and subscription details from products in  WooCommerce. I am using [**Sumo Subscriptions** plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/sumo-subscriptions-woocommerce-subscription-system/16486054) and get this description below the Product name.

I have tried adding the following to the CSS file:

```css
.price.grid-only { 
    display: none !important;
}
```

As well as trying to add *(to the theme `function.php` file)*:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10) ;
```

But am still seeing the following:
[image]

How to remove the price and subscription from products?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no indication that it's a programming question. It seems to be more about *using* Woocommerce than programming with it.If this is not the case, please [edit] the question to clarify what is being asked. See [ask].

Comment: As Sumo Subscriptions plugin is a commercial plugin with few sales and a non official WooCommerce plugin, you will have to search in this plugin support threads and ask there, as you will not get anything on StackOverFlow… Now if you provide a live link to your website may be someone can answer with some convenient CSS.